# Recursive function into non-recursive

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have to express $a_n$ in terms of $n$. How do I convert this recursive function into a non-recursive one? Is there any methodology to follow in order to do the same with any recursively defined function? Thanks.

$$a_n = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }n=1\\ a_{n-1}+n-1 & \text{if }n \ge 2 \end{cases} $$

So the results would be:

$$
a_1 = 0 \\
a_2 = 1 \\
a_3 = 3 \\
a_4 = 6 \\
a_5 = 10 \\
... \\
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, with the corrected recursion formula we get:

$$a_1=0\\
a_2=0+(2-1)=0+1\\
a_3=0+(2-1)+(3-1)=0+1+2\\
a_4=0+(2-1)+(3-1)+(4-1)=0+1+2+3\\\vdots\\
a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Comment: That's true. I'm sorry I made a mistake transcribing the function. Take a look now to the edit.

Comment: OK, but now either your recursion formula is wrong or your table below it is wrong. Please check again.

Comment: I think now is everything OK. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there isn't really a general method for doing this I believe but you can often try to break these problems into parts. The '$n$' term means that for each successive term we add on the term number, so by the $m$'th term this will have contributed $2+3+4+\ldots + m$. The -1 term means that (obviously) each time we take away another one. So what is the overall effect of these terms by the time we're at the $m$'th term?